# How does Python's .join work?

Tags: python

I was suggested the below solution but I didn't understand this line           `cmd += "("+ ",".join(args) +")"` of the below code.
I got frustated because of this.Can someone please help me

Question is Reading an input like this

```
12
insert 0 5
insert 1 10
insert 0 6
print 
remove 6
append 9
append 1
sort 
print
pop
reverse
print
```

My arttempt in Python language

```
n = input()
l = []
for _ in range(n):
    s = raw_input().split()
    cmd = s[0]
    args = s[1:]
    if cmd !="print":
        cmd += "("+ ",".join(args) +")"
        eval("l."+cmd)
    else:
        print l
```

Comment: Do you understand `",".join(args)` by itself...?

Comment: What you trying to archive ?

Comment: No I don't understand .deceze

Comment: Rahul I just want to understand this line cmd += "("+ ",".join(args) +")"

Comment: `eval()` is a terrible solution for this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice. You could for example use `getattr(l, cmd)(*(int(arg) for arg in args))` in this particular case. Even uncontrolled getattr can be evil.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Answer (score 2):

This line is there to ensure that your command is in the right syntax and has brackets and comma when you call it! I wrote it clearer in the code below:

```
cmd = 'insert'
arg1 = '1'
arg2 = '3'
arg3 = '10'

cmd = cmd + "(" + ",".join((arg1, arg2, arg3)) + ")"
print cmd
```

Output:

```
insert(1,3,10)
```

Comment: "," is nothing but the separator for arguments We can use anything instead of , like / as well.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following input line:

```
insert 1 10
```

So `s` is the list `["insert", "1", "10"]`.  Note that the list elements are all strings.

So `cmd` is `"insert"` and `args` is `["1", "10"]`.

Now here's the part that you didn't understand.  First, `",".join(args)` just creates a single string composed of the elements of `arg`, separated by commas:  `"1,10"`.

This is then wrapped in parentheses:  `"(1,10)"`.  Finally, it is appended to `cmd` resulting in the string `"insert(1,10)"`.

It then prepends `"l."` to this, resulting in the string `"l.insert(1,10)"`.  This is then passed to `eval`.

So it's invoking the `insert` method on the list `l`, inserting the value `10` at position `1`.  I.e., it's executing `l.insert(1,10)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom. Understood completely :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is what does the following line mean:

```
cmd += "("+ ",".join(args) +")"
```

`cmd` is a variable (with a string).

`+=` is an operator which adds the right side to the left side.

`"("` is a string containing a left parens.

`+` is an operator that adds the left and right of itself.

`",".join(args)` this makes the list, `args`, into a string separated by commas. For example:

```
args =['bob','sue','tom'], then: 
",".join(args)
> bob,sue,tom
```

again, `+` is an operator that adds the left and right of itself.

`)` is a string containing a right parens.

Thus, if args is ['bob',sue','tom], and cmd is names, then the output of this line would be:

```
cmd = "names"
args =["bob","sue","tom"]
cmd += "("+ ",".join(args) +")"
print cmd
> names(bob,sue,tom)
```